# D3.js histogram bin size increments

Tags: javascript, d3.js, histogram

I am attempting to create a histogram of ambulance response times (in seconds). The sample code from D3.js works very well. I am able to put together a nice histogram easily. It even converts the response times in seconds to mm:ss format. 
What I am trying to accomplish and need your help with is this; **How to make the bins be 60 seconds (1 minute)** If you run the following code you will see the bins are increments of 50 seconds. This is non-intuitive for most people. How would you specify the exact number for the bins? For response times I want the bins to be 1 minute (60 seconds), but for off-loading patient at hospital I would like the bins to be in 5 minute intervals (300 seconds). What ever the case I would like to ask for your assistance to make the bins be precise values. 
Shown below is my code with data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
body {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.bar rect {
    fill: thistle;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar text {
    fill: black;
}

.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: cornsilk;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```
    var values = [212,
        279,
        264,
        411,
        189,
        343,
        207,
        424,
        550,
        302,
        317,
        315,
        29,
        227,
        367,
        163,
        581,
        96,
        375,
        313,
        548,
        570,
        329,
        269,
        953,
        238,
        195,
        183,
        384,
        353,
        258,
        465,
        208,
        273,
        155,
        344,
        355,
        354,
        88,
        364,
        143,
        407,
        207,
        437,
        142,
        234,
        234,
        193,
        308,
        416,
        445,
        327,
        293,
        327,
        232,
        319,
        209,
        498,
        236,
        427,
        241,
        164,
        0,
        157,
        295,
        337,
        430,
        218,
        390,
        231,
        402,
        301,
        472,
        349,
        133,
        311,
        396,
        452,
        490,
        189,
        282,
        297,
        296,
        413,
        102,
        219,
        190,
        371,
        390,
        454,
        467,
        302,
        221,
        547]
    // Formatters for counts and times (converting numbers to Dates).
    var formatCount = d3.format(",.0f"),
            formatTime = d3.time.format("%H:%M"),
            formatMinutes = function (d) {
                return formatTime(new Date(2012, 0, 1, 0, d));
            };
    //this is the positioning of the chart
    var margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, 600])
            .range([0, width]);

    // These are the number of bins in the histogram.
    var data = d3.layout.histogram()
            .bins(x.ticks(10))
            (values);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
                    return d.y;
                })])
            .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom")
            .tickFormat(formatMinutes);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")";
            });

    bar.append("rect")
            .attr("x", 1)
            .attr("width", x(data[0].dx) - 1)
            .attr("height", function (d) {
                return height - y(d.y);
            });
    //this block of code makes the tick values showing how many fall into the bin
    bar.append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".75em")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("x", x(data[0].dx) / 2)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function (d) {
                return formatCount(d.y);
            });

    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this.  First, manually calculate your ticks:

```
var ticks = d3.range(0, x.domain()[1] + 1, 60);
```

This will create an array of:

```
[0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 360, 420, 480, 540, 600]
```

Then feed this to `d3.histogram`:

```
var data = d3.layout.histogram()
  .bins(ticks)
  (values);
```

Finally fix your axis ticks:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickValues(ticks)
  .tickFormat(formatMinutes);
```

---

All together:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    
    .bar rect {
      fill: thistle;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    
    .bar text {
      fill: black;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: cornsilk;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
  </style>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var values = [212,
        279,
        264,
        411,
        189,
        343,
        207,
        424,
        550,
        302,
        317,
        315,
        29,
        227,
        367,
        163,
        581,
        96,
        375,
        313,
        548,
        570,
        329,
        269,
        953,
        238,
        195,
        183,
        384,
        353,
        258,
        465,
        208,
        273,
        155,
        344,
        355,
        354,
        88,
        364,
        143,
        407,
        207,
        437,
        142,
        234,
        234,
        193,
        308,
        416,
        445,
        327,
        293,
        327,
        232,
        319,
        209,
        498,
        236,
        427,
        241,
        164,
        0,
        157,
        295,
        337,
        430,
        218,
        390,
        231,
        402,
        301,
        472,
        349,
        133,
        311,
        396,
        452,
        490,
        189,
        282,
        297,
        296,
        413,
        102,
        219,
        190,
        371,
        390,
        454,
        467,
        302,
        221,
        547
      ]
      // Formatters for counts and times (converting numbers to Dates).
    var formatCount = d3.format(",.0f"),
      formatTime = d3.time.format("%H:%M"),
      formatMinutes = function(d) {
        return formatTime(new Date(2012, 0, 1, 0, d));
      };
    //this is the positioning of the chart
    var margin = {
        top: 30,
        right: 30,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 30
      },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 600])
      .range([0, width]);

    // These are the number of bins in the histogram.
    var ticks = d3.range(0, x.domain()[1] + 1, 60);
    
    var data = d3.layout.histogram()
      .bins(ticks)
      (values);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })])
      .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .tickValues(ticks)
      .tickFormat(formatMinutes);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")";
      });

    bar.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 1)
      .attr("width", x(data[0].dx) - 1)
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.y);
      });
    //this block of code makes the tick values showing how many fall into the bin
    bar.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("x", x(data[0].dx) / 2)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return formatCount(d.y);
      });

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. This is exactly what I was looking for! Your answer works perfectly.

Comment: Now how do I indicate this post as being completed ? There used to be a flag that indicates a question was answered; but I don't see that here.

Comment: @DavidFortMyers, you are welcome.  To make the answer accepted, click the checkmark at the top of my answer.

Comment: Clicking the pale gray check was certainly not intuitive. Once again thank you for all your kind assistance.